How to write a Procedural Macro for function transformation?
I'm trying to write a procedural macro in Rust, and I need some help. Let's call the macro r. This macro should transform a function such that if it returns a value, it instead returns () and writes the original return value to a given pointer. An example will make it clearer.
Here's the original code:
#[r]
fn bar(a: usize) -> usize {
    if a % 2 == 0 {
        return 0;
    }
    1
}

This should be transformed to:
fn bar(a: usize, res: *mut usize) {
    if a % 2 == 0 {
        unsafe { *res = 0; }
        return;
    }
    unsafe { *res = 1; }
}

I've looked into the documentation for proc_macro and syn, but I haven't been able to find an example that accomplishes this.
Could someone please guide me on how to write such a macro? If providing a complete solution is too time-consuming, any pointers on where to start or what to look into would be greatly appreciated.

Setting up a attribute macro can be found here: How do I create a proc_macro_attribute?

@kmdreko, I know that. But I don't need a simple proc_macro, like in the proc_macro documentation. I need a macro to change all the return statements. How can I do that?

I would not recommend trying to modify all the return statements and instead simply act on the returned value. You can do this by wrapping the body in an inner function. I would transform the original code into this:
unsafe fn bar(arg0: usize, res: *mut usize) {
    fn bar(a: usize) -> usize {
        if a % 2 == 0 {
            return 0;
        }
        1
    }

    unsafe { *res = bar(arg0); }
}

The key point here is that the original body of the function is left unaffected. In addition to making the transformation simpler, it also ensures the tokens aren't modified in non-obvious ways meaning that a compiler error will continue to look correct and IDEs continue to work correctly. Otherwise users may see weird and potentially annoying behavior.
I've also opted to rewrite the argument names into a consistent arg0, arg1, res format in the outer function to ensure there is no conflict with the name of the mutable pointer argument.
Now to actually write it needs a bit of finesse but its not too bad. Using syn and quote helper libraries:
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use syn::token::Unsafe;
use syn::{parse_macro_input, FnArg, Ident, ItemFn, Pat, PatIdent, ReturnType, Signature};

#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn r(_args: TokenStream, input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let func = parse_macro_input!(input as ItemFn);
    let func_name = func.sig.ident.clone();

    assert!(func.sig.asyncness.is_none(), "async not supported");

    let (outer_inputs, outer_argument_names) = {
        let mut inputs = func.sig.inputs.clone();
        let argument_names = (0..inputs.len())
            .map(|i| syn::parse_str::<Ident>(&format!("arg{i}")).unwrap())
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();

        for (input, argument) in inputs.iter_mut().zip(&argument_names) {
            match input {
                FnArg::Receiver(_) => panic!("self not supported"),
                FnArg::Typed(arg) => {
                    *arg.pat = Pat::Ident(PatIdent {
                        attrs: Vec::new(),
                        by_ref: None,
                        mutability: None,
                        ident: argument.clone(),
                        subpat: None,
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        inputs.push(syn::parse_str("res: *mut usize").unwrap());

        (inputs, argument_names)
    };

    let outer_signature = Signature {
        unsafety: Some(Unsafe::default()), // assigning to mutable pointer is unsafe
        constness: None,                   // assigning to mutable pointer is not allowed in const contexts
        output: ReturnType::Default,
        inputs: outer_inputs,
        ..func.sig.clone()
    };

    quote::quote! {
        #outer_signature {
            #func

            unsafe { *res = #func_name(#(#outer_argument_names),*) }
        }
    }
    .into()
}

As a follow up, I would recommend not using the same name for the source function and wrapped function since it is usually confusing if bar looks like it takes one argument but actually takes two. You could provide an argument to your attribute like this #[r(bar_assign)] to provide a new name for example.
More work may be done if you want the type of res to change based on the return type of the inner function. More work may be done if you want this to handle async transparently. I think this handles generic arguments but I've not tested it.

thank you for your response. But I need this macros because I can't return from a function. So this way is incorrect for me.

"I can't return from a function" - I don't understand what this means. Do you mean your transformation can't be done using a simple return value? Is your sample above (assigning to res based on returned value) not reflective of what you need to do? If so, can you edit your post with what you actually want to do? Perhaps with a more elaborate example?

I don't see any reason to edit my post because I accurately conveyed that the function should not return anything after the transformation.
I am trying to use Coroutine from the standard library. I can't generalize return in Coroutine while maintaining performance. The only efficient way to pass the result of a Coroutine that came to my mind is to use pointers. I want to create a procedural macros that will transform a function code to coroutine code. For this, I need to change all return statements to using ptr.

That is valuable information that should've been in the post. Functions and coroutines are not the same. However, it very much sounds like an XY problem and I'm fairly confident you don't need macros at all. I'll remove this answer if you update your post with your actual coroutine code and practical goal.

I'm afraid that I'll just discourage people from even thinking about this issue if I mention the word "Coroutine." I'm having trouble with this part of writing my macro, specifically the part that doesn't interact with Coroutines. The question remains the same: I need to replace all return expressions. Usually, it's a good solution to try to avoid the problem, but my question is specifically about replacing all return expressions.
You can leave your answer to the question. Your answer might be helpful to others who can work around their limitations using your method.

You can't literally replace all return statements, simply because you might not see them all. For example:
macro_rules! foo {
    ($e:expr) => {
        return $e;
    }
}

makes foo!(bar); semantically equivalent to return bar; but currently there is no way for you to find out, because you only get the tokens foo, !, (, bar, ), ; and there is currently no way for you to expand_expr arbitrary expressions eagerly:

Currently only expressions expanding to literals will succeed, although this may be relaxed in the future.


This is partially possible. Why only partially? It is impossible to property handle try-expressions (the question mark operator) and macros that contain return statements. Otherwise, it is possible, but it took me 164 lines of code, and I'm still not sure I've covered all cases (an implicit return can come from any block within any other block, and I'm not confident my imagination covered every scenario). I couldn't find a way to do this with a ready-made function and had to parse almost "manually" using syn. For those interested, the solution lies in recursively processing all syn::Block and all syn::Expr + syn::Local within it.
I'm not attaching my code here because it probably doesn't handle all cases and has a worst-case time complexity of O(2*N), but if you're completely stuck, feel free to ask for it in the comments of this answer.

As @cafce25 explained, you cannot do that perfectly because macros can hide returns. Still, not handling macros can be good enough for you.
syn::visit_mut::VisitMut can be of help here (note: it is guarded behind the feature visit-mut). It allows you to structurally replace parts of the AST. Implement visit_expr_mut(), match the Expr for Expr::Return, and if it matches, replace it with your transformation (using parse_quote!()). Remember to call syn::visit_mut::visit_expr_mut() too to handle sub-expressions.
Some notes:

Remember return is not the only way to return from a function. Also handle ? and the last expression in the function.
You cannot replace return <expr> with unsafe { *res = <expr>; return } because that will mean that the expression <expr> will be considered as written inside unsafe block, allowing it to execute unsafe constructs without the user writing unsafe, which would be unsound.
Name mangling: do not name it res. __my_macro_name__return_slot will be a better name with less chance of colliding with user-written names.
Even if you don't perfectly handle macros, you can still improve the state of things by looking into macros. has_hidden_return!(456) won't be handled, but does_not_add_return!(return 456) will. Do that by overriding visit_expr_macro_mut() and visit_stmt_macro_mut(), and trying to parse the TokenStream as Expr/Stmt, respectively.

